# Add an rss feed subscription to Outlook via Javascript (ActiveX)?

Tags: javascript, rss, outlook, activex, subscription

I want to provide a link to automatically add my rss feed into outlook.
So subscribe to the feed with outlook.

I get the already subscribed RSS Feeds which are Folder Objects then, but create a new
folder doesn't make the new folder to a rss feed subscription. I can get the Feed URL from
the StorageItem associated with the Folder object (via GetStorage("IPM.Sharing.Binding.In", 2) ). That StorageItem holds the feed Url in it's Subject property. But when I create a new Folder and set the StorageItem's Subject to the new feed url, doesn't make the folder to a subscription folder too.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

It revealed, that I neither need ActiveX nor Javascript. Just create a link with the protocol "outlookfeed://" and you are done, at least in IE and FireFox. Other Browsers I haven't tested yet.